Reporting services page not showing (HTTP 500) and showing in incognito mode
I have a very strange issue. I have a server (OS 2022) with SSRS 2022 installed on it. The users are have a very strange issue, when they launch the URL of SSRS using a private navigation (incognito mode) it is working fine but it is never working using "normal" navigation. We tried to clear cache and data from the browser setting, nothing changed. We are having this issue with both Chrome and EDGE.
I have checked the logs in SSRS server, nothing really relevant...
Here is the error we have:
SSRS Error
Thank you for your help,
Aniss

Check the logs again. It's the only place you'll find the reason for a 500 error. Increase the log level if necessary.
